# Data not fetching of current user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the data of current log in user but i am getting the result of all users in database. While in all views same problem is accure please help.
My code is given
My view is personal.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>
    <h1 class="text-success text-center">Profile</h1><br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach($data as $value)
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>{{ $value ->tname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Father Name</td>
            <td>{{ $value ->fname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{ $value ->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Official Email</td>
            <td>{{ $value ->off_email}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Generate Report</label>
        <div class="radio form-control">
            <label class="col-md-4"><input type="radio" name="status" value="conf" >Personal</label>

            <label class="col-md-4"><input type="radio" name="status"  value="general">Publications</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> Generate PDF</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> Generate CSV</button>
    <button class="btn btn primary"><a href="home">Go to Home</a></button><br>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
        <h3 class="text-success text-center">Complete your publication's detail</h3><br>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
            <form action="pub" method="post">

                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

                <div>
 @endsection
```

My controller is EducationController.php and its code is given.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\education;
use DB;
class EducationController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        //
        $data['data'] = DB::table('users')->get();
        if(count ($data)>0){
            return view('personal',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('personal');
        }
    }


}
```

My route code is given here.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/personal','EducationController@personal');
```

Please help me. I dont know how to use the current user in all views. I am login while in result I am getting the result of all users which is stored in database. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `@foreach` which implies you expect multiple users in your view.

If you only want to show details for the logged in user you should do:

```
<?php

class EducationController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {

        if(\Auth::check()){
            $user = \Auth::user();
            return view('personal',compact('user'));
        }
        else
        {
            return view('personal');
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>
    <h1 class="text-success text-center">Profile</h1><br>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    @if (isset($user))
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>{{ $user->tname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Father Name</td>
            <td>{{ $user->fname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Official Email</td>
            <td>{{ $user->off_email}}</td>
        </tr>
     @endif
    </table>
    // Rest of view
```

Comment: not working Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\resources\views\personal.blade.php)

Comment: waaw its works. thanks alot, but how I can use it in other views.?

Comment: What was $data['data'] is now $user

Comment: how can I use it for other tables like publications

Comment: I don't understand. The problem in your question is how to pass the currently signed in user to a view. I don't see how that applies to anything but a user. Do you mean the publications of the currently signed in user ? If so read up on [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your code is actually for getting all users. You should do it like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\education;
use DB;
class EducationController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('personal',compact('user'));
        }
    }


}
```

then in your view:

```
  <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td>{{ $user->tname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Father Name</td>
            <td>{{ $user->fname}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Official Email</td>
            <td>{{ $user->off_email}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Note that if you have multiple auth, you must specify your guard :

```
Auth::guard('yourguard')->user();
```

otherwise, your user will return a null.